# template parameter to dynamic_pointer_cast

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, c++11, casting

What's wrong with this code?

```
class Event;

class EventPtr : public std::shared_ptr<Event>
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    std::shared_ptr<T> castTo() {
        return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(this);
    }
};
```

I get the following compile error: *no matching function for call to 'dynamic_pointer_cast'*

Below is the usage:

```
void SomeClass::onEvent(EventPtr event)
{
    auto e = event.castTo<SomeEvent>();
    // using casted event
}
```

Comment: For one thing `dynamic_pointer_cast` takes a reference not a pointer, but are you sure you are compiling with c++11 support?

Comment: Also, have you included `<memory>`?

Comment: yes, it's c++11, and <memory> is included

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are just calling the function passing a pointer in place of a reference. Try:

```
return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(*this); // note the "star"
```